# Create Julia Tuple

Tags: julia

As I am trying to understand metaprogramming in Julia: What is missing in this code, respectively, how can I call the proper constructor of `Tuple`?

```
x = (:a, :b)
p = quote
    f_a = 3
    f_b = 4
    y = Tuple($([Symbol("f_", k) for k in x]...))
end
```

This will generate me the following code:

```
quote
    f_a = 3
    f_b = 4
    y = Tuple(f_a, f_b)
end
```

This is of course wrong, because Tuple has no appropriate constructor. I would like to have `y` being a Tuple in the end, but I don't see yet how to get the additional parentheses.

In other words, what is missing in this code:

```
x = (:a, :b)

p = quote
    f_a = 3
    f_b = 4
    y = ($([Symbol("f_", k) for k in x]...))
end
eval(p)
@assert isa(y, Tuple)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a comma,

```
x = (:a, :b)

p = quote
    f_a = 3
    f_b = 4
    y = ($([Symbol("f_", k) for k in x]...),) # added a comma here
end
eval(p)
@assert isa(y, Tuple)
```

The following might be instructive

```
julia> (3)
3

julia> (3,)
(3,)

julia> typeof(ans)
Tuple{Int64}
```